# Htaccess - redirect old site with variables to new subdomain

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, basically, the old site is whole made in flash and I want to switch to html version, assign it to subdomain, and keep all links working. An example url for the flash looks like this:

*http://site.com/dir/?language=french#/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg*

From the url above, I need to get pretty one, like this:

*http://dir.site.com/FR/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg*

Of course, if the language variable is not specified I would like to assign a default lang "EN" to the url, so I can make the language controller switch (there will be only two languages - french/FR and english/EN).

My current htaccess file (http://site.com/dir/.htaccess) looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dir.site.com/$1 [R=301,L,P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Now I need only convert the language variable like in the example above, but when I'm trying to set another rule in htaccess, my site gets redirect loop error :/

As for the hash (#) in the url - I made JS in the index.php file (which is my first controller), so the only thing left is the language...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
       location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/, ""));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How does the url look without the language query parameter?

Comment: it looks like this: _site.com/dir/#/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg_

Comment: mod_rewrite cannot do substring. What I mean is that `?language=french` cannot be made `/FR/` using .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} language=french [NC]
RewriteRule ^dir/.*$ http://dir.site.com/FR? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^dir/.*$ http://dir.site.com/EN? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Redirects as follows

```
http://site.com/dir/#/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg [OR]
http://site.com/dir/?language=english#/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg
 => http://dir.site.com/EN#/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg

http://site.com/dir/?language=french#/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg
 => http://dir.site.com/FR#/gallery/folder1/image1.jpg
```

Comment: Yes. looks like it should work, but it doesn't :/ This redirects me to the subdomain but still shows the `?language=french` in the url. Thanks.